# Avoid compiling definition of inline function multiple times

Tags: c++, inline

I have a non-template struct in a header file:

```cpp
struct X {
    constexpr X() : /* ... */ { /* ... */ }
    constexpr void f() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

With functions of varying size. This is used in a lot of different translation units, and each function appears in multiple object files for them to be discarded in the final executable.

What I want is for the definitions to be in a single object file, and the other translation units can either inline the function or use an external definition (something like the `extern inline` semantics from C). How can I do that?

It seems to work with templates and `extern template`:

```cpp
namespace detail {

template<std::nullptr_t>
struct X_base {
    constexpr X_base() // ...
    constexpr void f() // ...
};

extern template struct X_base<nullptr>;

}

struct X : detail::X_base<nullptr> {
    using X_base::X_base;
};

// X.cpp
#include <X.hpp>

template struct detail::X_base<nullptr>;
```

But are there any major downsides to this (longer symbol names, confusing to read, needs documentation, etc.), or are there any easier ways to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the functions are actually emitted in each object file?  If the compiler successfully inlines a function at every call in a translation unit (including the vacuous case of there being no calls), it need not do so.  If some functions are large and thus typically not inlined, you could define them elsewhere.

Comment: @DavisHerring The problem is that some of them are large (so not inlined and emit a definition) but are also used in `constexpr` contexts, so can't be provided elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn’t have the notion of an inline function that must be **emitted** in one translation unit and which therefore certainly need not be emitted anywhere else.  (It doesn’t have the notion of emitting object code at all, but the point is that there’s no syntax that says “I promise this definition is ODR-identical to the others except that it and only it bears this marker.” so that compilers *could* do that.)

However, the behavior you want is the obvious way of implementing C++20 **modules**: because the definition of an inline function in a module is known to be the only definition, it can and should be emitted once in case several importing translation units need an out-of-line copy of it.  (Inlining is still possible because the definition is made available in a compiler-internal form as part of building the module.)  Bear in mind that member functions defined in a class in a module are not automatically inline, although `constexpr` still implies it.

Another ugly workaround is to make non-inline **wrappers** to be used outside of constant evaluation, although this could get unwieldy if there were multiple levels of constexpr functions that might also be used at runtime.